# How to give provider name in oracle connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have following string without provider name.I want to give provider name in oracle connection.How can i give.I am using ODP.NET.Code is here

```
string strconn = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1501)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl.222.1.3)));User ID=pp;password=pp";
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(strconn))
        {
           Response.Write("aa");
        }
```

I want to  give providername  "Oracle.DataAccess.Client" to oracle connection.How can i give to provider name and if not give how oracle connection know I am using which provider name?

Comment: There is a lot of information available about connection strings at www.connectionstrings.com, you should be able to find what you are looking for there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OracleConnection` doesn't need to know the provider name. `OracleConnection` already knows you're using Oracle.

Comment: So then why we are putting in web.config file provider name =  "Oracle.DataAccess.Client"?IF oracle connection already know

Comment: @WaqasAli  That's if you're using it with some generic tool that can work with multiple databases, for example the `SqlDataSource` control.